# Recuperate user's details into fake JSON server

Tags: json, typescript, angular-2+

This is the 'details.ts' which define the user's details that I want to recuperate in a JSON (user's role, logintime, duration).

```
import {AuthenticationService} from '../_services';

import { User } from '../_models';

export class Details { 

authenticationService : AuthenticationService;

currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;

role = this.currentUser.role;
logintime = this.authenticationService.today;
duree = this.authenticationService.timeLeft;

}
```

and this is the service "details.service.ts" which implement the method create and get:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Details} from './details';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DetailsService  {
apiURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

constructor(private http: HttpClient)    { }

httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
}  


createEmployee(details): Observable<Details> {
return this.http.post<Details>(this.apiURL + '/details', 
JSON.stringify(details), this.httpOptions)
.pipe(
  retry(1),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
}

getEmployees(): Observable<Details> {
return this.http.get<Details>(this.apiURL + '/details')
.pipe(
  retry(1),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
}
deleteEmployee(id){
return this.http.delete<Details>(this.apiURL + '/details/' + id, 
this.httpOptions)
.pipe(
  retry(1),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
}


handleError(error) {
let errorMessage = '';
if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // Get client-side error
  errorMessage = error.error.message;
} else {
  // Get server-side error
  errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: 
${error.message}`;
}
window.alert(errorMessage);
return throwError(errorMessage);
}

}
```